# iOS/php how to load profile pictures from server

Tags: php, ios, image

I am an IOS newbie and am trying to design an iOS app that can work with php/mysql backend of a website.  The website has pictures uploaded by people including profile pics.  Normally, the pics are sized on the fly by php depending on layout and loaded.   But my understanding is that for IOS app, you need to have 3 versions of each photo for different screen resolutions.

Note for other web calls I am using web service returning json on server and jsonserialization on app end.

What is best practice for serving profile pics from a server?  Do you to send the screen size to the server as a parameter and then return the appropriate url for the appropriate size?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can load images of any size into the image view. If the image view is larger than the image then you can see broken pixels.

The best practice is to maintain different images which matches your imageView.

Comment: so would you detect the iPhone/ipad screen size and pass as parameter to web service?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to retrieve image from flickr based on the device. While creating the image url for request change the image name for the device. here in this case its just m - medium and l- large image.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_m.jpg", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"id"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];
}
else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_l.jpg", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"id"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];
}
[self.photoURLsImage addObject:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString]]];
```